# BIOSのプログラムでINT 0x13などでフロッピーディスクなどを操作できますが、USBのデータを読み書きするものは無いのですか？

Tags: assembly

BIOSのプログラムでINT 0x13などでフロッピーディスクなどを操作できますが、USBのデータを読み書きするものは無いのですか？

Comment: もしかしたら、この記事が参考になるかも。[USB flash drive and int 13h extension read USB drive contents](https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/usb-flash-drive-and-int-13h-extension-read-usb-drive-contents_8_8_10253913.html)

Answer (score 3):

ここみたいに技術者の集まる場所で 「 USB のデータ」などと書くと HID だの CDC だのとツッコミが入ります（っていうかオイラが入れます）もっと正確に MSC (Mass Storage Class) と書くべきでしょう。

https://teratail.com/questions/220939
でも質疑応答されていますが `INT 13H` は 8086 CPU の 16bit 世代におけるディスク装置のアクセスインターフェイスです。次にあげるような理由によりサポートされていない、ないしは、サポートされていてもそもそも発行する手段がないです。

- x64 アプリから `INT 13H` を使うような ABI は規定されていない
- 今のディスク装置は当時のものよりはるかに容量が増えていて `INT 13H` で使われていた CHS/LBA ではアクセスできない
- リセット直後処理が `BIOS` でなくて `UEFI` になっていて、そもそも 16bit で動作するように (CPU/マザボが) 作られていない
- その `INT 13H` を発行するであろう 16bit アプリ (= MS-DOS / Win3.1 アプリ) は x64 Windows ではサポートされていない
- 独自 OS を自分で作るためのブートストラップであるなら一見必要そうに見えるが、上記のような理由により 16bit OS は今のマシンでは動かないし `INT 13H` を使うことはありえない

なぜ `INT 13H` が必要なのかまで立ち返ると、これは XY 問題と呼ぶべきでしょう。単なる技術的興味であるなら「無い」で終了、そうでないならこの質問をするに至った元の要望に立ち返るとよいでしょう。

Comment: 質問するに至った元の要望は、UEFIからusbのブートプログラムを起動して、ハードディスクとusbの間でデータの読み書きをしたかったからです。

Comment: 読み書きするだけなら Windows 配下で行うほうが圧倒的に簡単ですし、それをしたくないということは要するにオレオレ OS １つ作りたいってことですよね。道のりは遠く険しく長いでしょう。数年の勉強で足りるでしょうか？　とりあえず遠くからお祈りしておきます。

Comment: osの実装までするとはいってませんが、UEFIの使い方を知りたかったです。

Comment: おそらく 90% 以上のプログラマは UEFI の仕様詳細を知る必要は一生無い（ PC マザボ・拡張基板の組み込みプログラマにのみ関係する）でしょうが https://uefi.org/specifications に仕様書はあります（英語） UEFI にはマルウエアの起動を防ぐ機構があるので、ホビープログラマの自作ブートストラップは受け付けてくれないはずで、その意味でも敷居は高いでしょね。